# How to update artifact in run configuration after version update in gradle

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I have java project and I'm using gradle to build. When I change version in build.gradle then Intellij change name of artifact for example from "Gradle : xxx : xxx-1.45.war" to "Gradle : xxx : xxx-1.46.war". But new name is not updated in my saved run/debug configuration. There is any method to update run/debug configuration automatically or to make artifact name constans.

[Atifact print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuBGL.png)

[Run/Debug configuration print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DheQO.png)

Comment: Add screenshots of Project Structure | **Artifacts** page with the artifact selected and Run/Debug Configurations | **Deployment** tab with the artifact you deploy.